# Exception: Bad value (line 9, file "Code")

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to read my data from my firebase and write it in google sheet. When i run this Apps Script I got the error

> Exception: Bad value (line 9, file "Code")

```
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range=sheet.getRange(1,1,4,2);
  var data= getFirebaseData("Entries");
  Logger.log(data)
  range.setValues(JSON.parse(data))
}
function getFirebaseData(data){
  var firebaseUrl = "**";
  var secret = "**";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl,secret);
  var result = base.getData(data);
  return result;

}
```

the data in Firebase is like this:

```
Entries
  date:"09/09/2020"
  docAmount:88
  docNo:55
  partyName: "ffg"
```

Solutions that I might accept,(solve this issue)or (show a better way to do the process)

Comment: Which line is 9?

Comment: @TheMaster  ```range.setValues(JSON.parse(data))```

Comment: Shouldn't you then show us the log of  `data`?

Comment: Where should i look for it?

Comment: What does this line do? `Logger.log(data)`?

Comment: ```[20-09-11 15:24:05:476 IST] {vishal=1.0}
[20-09-11 15:24:05:481 IST] SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1```    This was the log and the new error that show up now after correcting the Url

Comment: Logger.log(data) ... Writes the string to the logging console

Comment: [Edit] to show the exact log or a representative sample. `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` says first character is `o` and that is unexpected. Usually means it's already a `o`bject and you don't have to parse it.

Comment: Try `range.setValue(JSON.stringify(data))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to write an object's (`data`) key/value pairs to two columns in a sheet. [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) accepts a 2D array, not an object, so you should first transform `data` to a 2D array:

```
const array = Object.keys(data).map(key => [key, data[key]]);
sheet.getRange(1, 1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
```

#### Note:

- Making the `range` dimensions dependent on the array dimensions (`array.length`, `array[0].length`) will give you more flexibility (what if the object has 5 properties instead of 4?).
- This will only work for simple objects, not if they have nested properties.

#### Reference:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))
- [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [getData(path, optQueryParameters)](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/reference#TOC-getData-path-optQueryParameters-)

Comment: it was helpful. Still, I couldn't complete the task. I have learned something out of this.

Comment: ```The parameters ((class)) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.```   .This was the error  that I ran into.it would be nice if you could direct me to a resource or solve this for me....An example that is accepted is as follows  ```range.setValues(JSON.parse("[[\"x \",\" y\"]]"))```...and the one that was in the log was ```{2020-09-11 17:45:02={docNo=65665.0, date=26/09/2020, docAmount=65665.0, partyName=bhxhd}, 2020-09-11 17:44:25={docAmount=8464.0, partyName=gsgs, docNo=63465.0, date=26/09/2020}}```

Comment: @vishalN if I understand you correctly, you want to write `{2020-09-11 17:45:02={docNo=65665.0, date=26/09/2020, docAmount=65665.0, partyName=bhxhd}, 2020-09-11 17:44:25={docAmount=8464.0, partyName=gsgs, docNo=63465.0, date=26/09/2020}}` to your spreadsheet. The solution I offered will only work for simple JS object literals, as the one you showed in your question, not for this. Where did you take this from? Can you provide the corresponding code?

Comment: Yes sir it was the data that is being fed to the spreadsheet from firebase. and your solution worked for me now.